# table not stretching to full width

Tags: html, css

I've looked at all of the other threads regarding this topic but none have been able to help me.

I'm creating forums, and I'm using a table to sort everything but it seems the table won't stretch to the full 100% width of the parent div. The parent div's width is 893.906 pixels (using percentages in css) and the table's width is 893 pixels. I've tried changing the display value but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/8wijqj

table html

```
<div class="module">
    <div class="module-header"><h4>Test Forum</h4></div>
    <div class="module-body">
        <table class="table discussions">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="width70">
                <col class="width10">
                <col class="width20">
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Thread Title</th>
                    <th class="count">Replies</th>
                    <th>Last Update</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.danksidecs.com/index.php?p=forums&c=viewthread&cid=1&fid=1&tid=1">This is a test thread!</a><br /><span class="text-muted">created <abbr class="timeago" title="2015-10-17 00:00:00"></abbr> by <abbr class="timeago">skruffysdeveloper</a></span></td>
                    <td class="count">0</td>
                    <td><abbr class="timeago" title="0000-00-00 00:00:00"></abbr> by None</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

css for module and table

```
.module {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.module-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #3B6C8E;
    border-left: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
    border-right: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
}
.module-header h4 {
    font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
.module-padding {
    padding: 10px;
}
.module-body {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.module-body p {color: #222222;}

.table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; display: block; }
.table thead { width: 100%; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-left: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-right: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); }
.table thead th { color: #ffffff; font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; }
.table tbody { width: 100%; }
.table tbody tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.table tbody td { font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; }

.width5 { width: 5%; }
.width10 { width: 10%; }
.width15 { width: 15%; }
.width20 { width: 20%; }
.width30 { width: 30%; }
.width45 { width: 45%; }
.width60 { width: 60%; }
.width65 { width: 65%; }
.width63 { width: 63%; }
.width70 { width: 70%; }
.width75 { width: 75%; }
```

Comment: `width:100%; border: 1px solid` add up to `100% + 2px`.

Comment: @Oriol they all have borders though, so it would all be the same. ^.^

Answer (score 6):

Try changing to this:

```
.table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; display: table; }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31xczjh3/)

Comment: Really? Have you any additional code? Because in http://jsfiddle.net/31xczjh3/ works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, if you remove `width: 100%;` from the module-header, it shrinks back to the same size as the module-body.

If you remove `display:block;` from the table, it expands up to match.

```
.module-header {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #3B6C8E;
  border-left: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
  border-right: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
}
.table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; }
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zqjLz2qu/

Comment: why does this help me with anything. I need the header to be 100%

Comment: The header is 100% even without this. Have a look at the fiddle.

Comment: I missed the `display:block` bit for the table - now added.

Answer (score 0):

`.module-header` has `width: 100%` and borders of 1px. Therefore, its total width is `100% + 2px`.

`.module-body` is a block, so it will fill `100%` of the containing block.

If you want to include the borders in `width` use `box-sizing: border-box`.

```css
.module {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.module-header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #3B6C8E;
  border-left: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
  border-right: 1px solid #3B6C8E;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.module-header h4 {
  font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
  line-height: 45px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.module-padding {
  padding: 10px;
}
.module-body {
  display: block;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.module-body p {color: #222222;}
.table { width: 100%; margin-bottom: 0; display: block; }
.table thead { width: 100%; background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51); border-left: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); border-right: 1px solid rgb(51, 51, 51); }
.table thead th { color: #ffffff; font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14px; }
.table tbody { width: 100%; }
.table tbody tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
.table tbody td { font-family: RobotoRegular, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; }
.width5 { width: 5%; }
.width10 { width: 10%; }
.width15 { width: 15%; }
.width20 { width: 20%; }
.width30 { width: 30%; }
.width45 { width: 45%; }
.width60 { width: 60%; }
.width65 { width: 65%; }
.width63 { width: 63%; }
.width70 { width: 70%; }
.width75 { width: 75%; }
```

```html
<div class="module">
  <div class="module-header"><h4>Test Forum</h4></div>
  <div class="module-body">
    <table class="table discussions">
      <colgroup>
        <col class="width70">
        <col class="width10">
        <col class="width20">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Thread Title</th>
          <th class="count">Replies</th>
          <th>Last Update</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="http://www.danksidecs.com/index.php?p=forums&c=viewthread&cid=1&fid=1&tid=1">This is a test thread!</a><br /><span class="text-muted">created <abbr class="timeago" title="2015-10-17 00:00:00"></abbr> by <abbr class="timeago">skruffysdeveloper</a></span></td>
          <td class="count">0</td>
          <td><abbr class="timeago" title="0000-00-00 00:00:00"></abbr> by None</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```